# Progressbar does not report progress

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, progress-bar

I have probably been staring too long at the same code, but I cannot seem to get the progressbar to work in the code below. Anyone got any tips?

```
private void doBackgroundTIFConverter(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string tifFileName = (string)e.Argument;
    bm = new Bitmap(tifFileName);
    int total = bm.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
    document.Open();
    cb = writer.DirectContent;
    for (int k = 0; k < total; ++k)
    {
        backgroundTIFConverter.ReportProgress(k / total * 100);
        bm.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, k);
        iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bm, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        // scale the image to fit in the page
        img.ScalePercent(72f / img.DpiX * 100);
        img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
        cb.AddImage(img);
        document.NewPage();
    }
    bm.Dispose();
    document.Close();
}

private void progressBackgroundTIFConverter(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    splitProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void completedBackgroundTIFConverter(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    splitButton.Enabled = true;
}


private void completedBackgroundTIFConverter(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    splitButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
backgroundTIFConverter.ReportProgress(k / total * 100);
```

This is a very common C# trap, you'll get integer division here.  k / total will always be zero.  Reorder the expression to:

```
backgroundTIFConverter.ReportProgress(k * 100 / total);
```

If you want to get to 100% then subtract 1 from total: k * 100 / (total-1)